# ¿Cómo hacer que cada columna de mi datagridview tenga un color determinado?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un datagridview donde muestro unos datos y quiero que cada columna de ese datagridview tenga un determinado color y ademas este color sea vea degradado y no se como hacerlo no me permite aplicarle propiedades con css agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo del lado del servidor. Un ejemplo sencillo es el siguiente: dividir el total de filas en 3 y la primera sección pintarla de una tonalidad oscura, la siguiente sección de un tono intermedio y la última sección de un tono claro:

```
Private Sub PintarRejilla(ByVal rejilla As GridView)

    Dim numeroFilas As Integer = rejilla.Rows.Count
    Dim contadorCambioColor As Integer = (numeroFilas / 3)
    Dim fila As Integer = 0
    Do While (fila < numeroFilas)
        If (fila <= contadorCambioColor) Then
            rejilla.Rows(fila).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
        ElseIf (fila <= (contadorCambioColor * 2)) Then
            rejilla.Rows(fila).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue
        Else
            rejilla.Rows(fila).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue
        End If
        fila = (fila + 1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Yo lo utilizo con C# y asp.net, espero que la conversión a VB.NET te sirva de guía. Si quieres cada columna de un color distinto, es muy similar, pero deberás acceder a cada celda de forma individual.